# How can I find the real MAC address if it has been changed?

Tags: windows, network-adapter, mac-address

One of my neighbors managed to get my credentials for ISP login and used my Internet connection without permission. I talked to the ISP about the unauthorized data use and they told me the MAC address used to log in. It is also in my account's logs. The device was manufactured by HP and there only two of them who could have done this, both HP.

There may be a chance he might have changed his MAC address, so I was wondering whether is there any way to figure out real MAC address of those devices. I will have physical access to those devices.

Comment: Why was this downvoted ?

Comment: What you are saying about changing MAC addresses does not make a lot of sense in context - why would he have changed the MAC address but left it as an HP ?

Comment: I just wanna confront him. He somehow got my username/password so I guess he's smart enough to change his MAC. If he changes his MAC then I won't be able to match it with what got from my ISP.

Comment: I just want to interrogate them and find out who used internet from my account. IP address is not going to work as we are assigned dynamic public IP address each time we log in. So all comes down to MAC with gets logged into ISP db and my personal ISP account as well. See, I just want recognize those devices somehow that they used to access internet from my account. That is why I want to be prepared if in case they have changed their MAC address after using Internet from my account.

Comment: AT Ramhound, you wrote "You can't. If a device's MAC address has been changed, then the real MAC Address, has been changed. MAC White-listing isn't an effective method to prevent authorized devices from connecting."   <-- But you know that what you wrote there is wrong, because when somebody answered saying "here is also freeware that will show both the current and original MAC address"  You replied in comment "This works if the device is the author's.." That latter comment means you know that the MAC addresses are distinct.

Comment: @barlop Whatever you say.

Comment: The MAC address the device holds will never change, but the MAC address your system uses for a specific device can be changed by way of software. If it has been changed via software, all normal reporting methods will return the changed version. You would need to query the device directly (eg have access to the system itself) to pull the hardwired MAC address (which is what software like macchanger does). If he never once used the real hardwired MAC, you're out of luck entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the device has Windows you can check to see if the MAC address has been changed by navigating to **Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections**. Right click on the network adapter and click on **Properties**. Click on **Configure** and select the **Advanced** tab. In the **Property** list locate **Network Address**. If **Not Present** is selected on the right then the NIC is using the original MAC address.

There is also freeware that will show both the current and original MAC address. [Technitium](https://technitium.com/tmac/) is one that comes to mind.

Comment: But the OP says "I will be having local access to those devices."  (I'm not sure what he means by that.)

Comment: I don't know what's troubling you in Local Acess. What I meant to say that I will have physical access to those two HP device.

Answer (score 1):

on linux changing and recovering original mac address is possible with the **macchanger** command:

```
macchanger --show wlan0
```

following information would be provided:

```
Current MAC:   44:ce:7d:7b:e7:9e 
Permanent MAC: f0:03:8c:4a:65:31
```

"Permanent MAC" would be your real one